# Is the indirect pronoun not always necessary? In these examples shouldn't they all have "le" or "les"?

Tags: pronombres, objetos-indirectos, clíticos

[image: Shouldn't all of them have "le" or "les"?]

Can someone explain what is going on here please?

The specific question is why does this sentence not have "les"
"El chef sirve comida a los niños."

It seems to me that it should be "El chef les sirve comida a los niños."
Duolingo marked it wrong though and Google translate says the les is not necessary either.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! First of all, never trust an automatic translation software. Secondly, what's your specific doubt? Have you tried to search the site? We have a lot of questions answered about the use of "le" as indirect object, what makes yours unique? Try to be as much specific as you can and you will get better answers. Please read the [answer] section for more information about how this site works.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the [ask] section. ^__^U

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three situations in which the indirect object pronoun, when the indirect object itself is explicitly mentioned, is required:

- **Verbs of the *gustar*-type**
  You cannot say *Algo gusta al niño*, you must say *le gusta al niño*
- **When the main object comes in front of the verb**
  If you say *al niño María __ sirve comida*, then a *le* is required.  There are even exceptions here, though, as if we are being particularly emphatic about how was being served the food we can omit the pronoun.
- **When the main object is a pronoun itself**
  In your examples, all the indirect objects are *niño* or *hijos*, which are not pronouns.  However, if they were *él/ella/Vd./mí/ti/etc*, then you must include the object pronoun.